# Camel case to Title case when there are special chars in between

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I need to change camel case to tile case even if there are special chars between

```
function camelToSentenceCase(text) {
  var result = text.replace(/([A-Z])/g,' $1');
  return result.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+result.slice(1);
}
```

*The function gives*

memberships 1 - contactGroupMembership - contactGroupId

*when input is*

**Memberships1 - contactGroupMembership - contactGroupId**
or **memberships1-contactGroupMembership-contactGroupId**

*while the expected result is*

Memberships 1 - **C**ontact Group Membership - **C**ontact Group Id

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) like the following way:

```js
var str = 'Memberships 1 - contact Group Membership - contact Group Id';

str = str.split(' ').map(c => c.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + c.slice(1)).join(' ');

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Sorry my input is camel case and your input is regular text. I am expecting the input to work for both types